# Printer Writer making me input twice to loop once

Tags: java

I know this is going to be stupid easy to fix but I've been battling it for an hour. I need to keep getting words from the user until they type "quit" and write them to a file in the process. But here's the problem, it comes up with the "Enter Word: " but then I type it and hit enter it doesnt take it until I write something a SECOND time then it works and uses the second one.

```
    //@Author: Tyler Cage
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class week12Program1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        //declaring the writer and initlizing it
        FileOutputStream fileByteStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/tyl3r/Desktop/test.txt");
        PrintWriter outFS = new PrintWriter(fileByteStream);
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        //declainrg ints
        int i = 0;

        //open file and print
        while(i<1){ 
         System.out.println("Enter word: ");   
         outFS.println(scnr.next());
         outFS.flush();
            if(scnr.next().equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                 System.out.println("Shutting down...");
                 fileByteStream.close();
                 i++;
         }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `scnr.next()` twice. So you have to enter something twice. If you want to use the previously entered text in your if statement you have to save it to a variable and use that variable. Java cannot guess that you are calling `scnr.next()` but actually don't really mean it and want the last result of that method call.

Comment: And just like that I completely missed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this section of code:

```
while(i<1){ 
      System.out.println("Enter word: ");   
      outFS.println(scnr.next()); // first time scanning input
      outFS.flush();
       if(scnr.next().equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){ // second time scanning input
             System.out.println("Shutting down...");
             fileByteStream.close();
             i++;
}
```

Actually you are reading the inputs 2 times so you need to enter the word another time to get the expected result.

To solve the problem you only need to declare variable to save input in it and then check the variable content at if condition:

```
while(i<1){ 
      System.out.println("Enter word: ");
      String word = scnr.next(); 
      outFS.println(word);
      outFS.flush();
        if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){ 
              System.out.println("Shutting down...");
              fileByteStream.close();
              i++;
}
```